# Problem with retargeting BVH bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, motion-capture, transform-orientation

I am trying to retarget bones (armature) from BVH file to my armature of the low poly model and I have a small problem. After retargeting my bones twist in the wrong direction. How to fix this? I created second bone skeleton (armature) and I retargeted bones from BVH file and for this new skeleton (blender default), everything works fine.
I think in my skeleton for low poly character rotation transforms are wrong, but I might be wrong. The animations seem to be ok but the bones placement and rotation aren't syncing.
Is there any option or method to fix this?
Thank you for help in advance :)

Problem with my armature.
[image]

Good version with defult blender armature. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First try Makewalk from Makehuman Blender Tools. It works beautifully.
If you didn't skin the rig yet, you can adjust Roll of bones, that tend to rotate wrong. In my case also helped using DAZ friendly BVH instead of Max or Motion Builder friendly ones. If you have problem only with end bones, which are not parents for any other bone effected by the animation, you can also adjust the rotation in Graph Editor by moving all frames of the channel with wrong rotation up or down.
Hope it helps, cause fighting with bvh's can be really annoying.